Clique doesn't show address of validator
I want to use Clique consensus
By default it writes  Coinbase.address as 0x0000...
I want to write always address of validator of a block
I have tried to add code to function "Finalize"
But it didnt work.
Maybe do you know how to solve this moment
My try that didn't help:
func (c *Clique) Finalize(chain consensus.ChainHeaderReader, header *types.Header, state *state.StateDB, txs []*types.Transaction, uncles []*types.Header, withdrawals []*types.Withdrawal) {
// No block rewards in PoA, so the state remains as is
signer, err := ecrecover(header, c.signatures)
header.Coinbase = signer
if err != nil {
    log.Info("Sealing result is not read by miner")
}

header.Root = state.IntermediateRoot(false)

}
